# Optional DateTime Parameter in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have set up an SQL Stored Procedure where the parameters are optional as in the front end any combination of these filters can have values or not have values. The only problem is when I come pass a null date in. SQL produces an error if I leave this null, however I have managed to do some reading around the problem and found that using the following should resolve the error:

```
SET @SessionStarted = ISNULL(@SessionStarted, GETDATE())
```

Which it does however, now it's not returning records it should be returning because it's only looking for records with the current date and time.

The parameter is defined as such:

```
@SessionStarted datetime = NULL,
```

And the where clause for this particular parameter is:

```
(@SessionStarted IS NULL OR VisitDate = @SessionStarted)
```

Is there anyway round this issue when a value for the can't be specified?

Comment: @SessionStarted is a DATETIME.  What data type is `VisitDate`?  If it's a DATETIME/DATETIME2/SMALLDATETIME, are values in that column a "date only" with the time portion stripped off?

Comment: VisitDate is a DateTime field same as the parameter

Comment: If you query the table with the `VisitDate` column, what does the data look like?  Do you see values like `2015-06-19 12:28:49.083`?  Or do the values look more like this `2015-06-19 00:00:00.000`?

Comment: By assigning the current datetime to the parameter, you are changing the logic. where did you get the error when the parameter was null?

Comment: are you sure the front end is actually passing in null and not mindate?

Comment: here is a sql fiddle using a null datetime parameter that works fine.  I think you might have an issue with what you're passing in as the parameter value. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/236c4/3

Comment: What was the error you were getting when you left the parameter as NULL?   There's no reason to get an error because of it, unless it's in a part of the code you haven't shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use a different date in your isnull and detect it. Something like '1900-01-01' feels like a good "known invalid" day to use in place of your NULL.

Answer (score 0):

When you assign current date time to a variable (like below)
SET @SessionStarted = ISNULL(@SessionStarted, GETDATE())

and compare it (like below) against a datetime dattyped column, which will never equal and will not return records.

(@SessionStarted IS NULL OR VisitDate = @SessionStarted)

You should make sure that what value your datetime column holds and what is your expected default value to be assigned to the variable in case NULL value is passed in.